# ID the Artists signature

Tags: character-identification

I have two watercolours (Birds & flowers blossom) but have not been able to find anything regarding who painted them.[image]

Comment: Looks Japanese to me.

Comment: it is stage name of author, if he/she is not a well-known artist, only few people within his/her cycle know him/her.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **怀谷** , from the idiom 虚**怀**若**谷**

[虛懷若谷](http://www.ichacha.net/%E8%99%9A%E6%80%80%E8%8B%A5%E8%B0%B7.html) means:

> *have a mind as open as a valley -- very modest; be extremely open-minded; be in a receptive mood; be open to conviction; free from pride and prejudices; from a sense of one's inadequacy; modest and open-minded*

Answer (score 2):

[image]

These are [Shang Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [oracle bone script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) shapes. The right hand character looks like either「冬」or「終」, and the left hand side character is either「月」or「夕」. Note that there was no difference between「冬・終」and「月・夕」in oracle bone script.

[image]

This is「圃」, also in a Shang Dynasty shape.